# Drupal newsletter module and restricted access category

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7 with newsletter module (https://drupal.org/project/newsletter). 
I created templates with the rispectives lists.
Unfortunately I am not able to see the real name of the category, I just see "Restricted access" for each on".

Anyway if I try to inspect the element the ID category is the right one and everything is working aside the incorrect email of the category.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue also. Apparently newsletters implementation of hook_entity_info is lacking an "access callback".

I put this code in my module, and defined my own access callback, but you could probably use an existing callback if you prefer.

```
function mymodule_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info){
    $entity_info["newsletter_template"]["access callback"] = "mymodule_template_access";
}

function mymodule_template_access($op, $entity, $account, $entity_type){
    return true;
}
```